# working with hrefs extracted from Beautifulsoup

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, python-unicode

I am a Python beginner learning web crawling.

On this one project, I had to retrieve some [hrefs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfkZN.png) and then to print out the text content within each of these href links. Here is my code so far:

```
import requests, bs4, os, webbrowser
url = 'http://www.constructeursdefrance.com/resultat/?dpt=53'
res = requests.get(url)
res.raise_for_status()

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'html.parser')
for a in soup.select('.link'):
    links = a.find('a').attrs['href']
```

I tried many things with the links but it would say "unicode is not callable".
How can I work with these links and eventually iterate over them to extract the text within?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you code is almost done, just a little change

```
import requests, bs4, os, webbrowser
url = 'http://www.constructeursdefrance.com/resultat/?dpt=53'
res = requests.get(url)
res.raise_for_status()

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'html.parser')
links = []
for div in soup.select('.link'):
    link = div.a.get('href')
    links.append(link)
print(links)
```

out:

```
['http://www.constructeursdefrance.com/concept-habitat/',
 'http://www.constructeursdefrance.com/maisons-bois-cruard/',
 'http://www.constructeursdefrance.com/passiva-concept/',
 'http://www.constructeursdefrance.com/les-constructions-de-la-mayenne/',
 'http://www.constructeursdefrance.com/maisonsdenfrance53/',
 'http://www.constructeursdefrance.com/lemasson53/',
 'http://www.constructeursdefrance.com/ecb53/',
 'http://www.constructeursdefrance.com/villadeale-53/',
 'http://www.constructeursdefrance.com/habitat-plus-53/']
```

select('.link') will return a list of div tag which has a child tag a, 
 so you can get a tag by `div.a` and than get href by `div.a.get('href')`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
import requests, bs4, os, webbrowser
url = 'http://www.constructeursdefrance.com/resultat/?dpt=53'
res = requests.get(url)
res.raise_for_status()

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
links = soup.findAll('a')

for link in links:
    try:
        print link.attrs['href']
    except:
        pass
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: But say like I want to have python retrieve some data from each of these links, how would I do that? It seems like I cannot separate these links to work with them individually...

Comment: You can do two things either store all links in a list variable and then iterate through that list and repeat the whole process for each link or you can do this directly in the for loop above and repeat above process for each link you are getting